# How to stop background running process immediately?

Tags: android

I am implementing Network Discovery process and I have an activity called `ActivityDiscovery` with background processing `AbstractDiscovery`. Once discovery is executed, it goes into the background processing and works till finish its processing. Even I press back button, it doesn't stop it processing. How can I implement to stop the background processing immediately if I press back button? My `AbstractDiscovery` is also shown below.

```
final public class ActivityDiscovery extends ActivityNet {
    private AbstractDiscovery mDiscoveryTask = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    private void startDiscovering() {            
        mDiscoveryTask.execute();
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractDiscovery extends AsyncTask<Void, HostBean, Void> {

    //private final String TAG = "AbstractDiscovery";

    protected int hosts_done = 0;
    final protected WeakReference<ActivityDiscovery> mDiscover;

    protected long ip;
    protected long start = 0;
    protected long end = 0;
    protected long size = 0;

    public AbstractDiscovery(ActivityDiscovery discover) {
        mDiscover = new WeakReference<ActivityDiscovery>(discover);
    }

    public void setNetwork(long ip, long start, long end) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    abstract protected Void doInBackground(Void... params);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        size = (int) (end - start + 1);
        if (mDiscover != null) {
            final ActivityDiscovery discover = mDiscover.get();
            if (discover != null) {
                discover.setProgress(0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(HostBean... host) {
        if (mDiscover != null) {
            final ActivityDiscovery discover = mDiscover.get();
            if (discover != null) {
                if (!isCancelled()) {
                    if (host[0] != null) {
                        discover.addHost(host[0]);
                    }
                    if (size > 0) {
                        discover.setProgress((int) (hosts_done * 10000 / size));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        if (mDiscover != null) {
            final ActivityDiscovery discover = mDiscover.get();
            if (discover != null) {
                if (discover.prefs.getBoolean(Prefs.KEY_VIBRATE_FINISH,
                        Prefs.DEFAULT_VIBRATE_FINISH) == true) {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) discover.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(ActivityDiscovery.VIBRATE);
                }
                discover.makeToast(R.string.discover_finished);
                discover.stopDiscovering();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (mDiscover != null) {
            final ActivityDiscovery discover = mDiscover.get();
            if (discover != null) {
                discover.makeToast(R.string.discover_canceled);
                discover.stopDiscovering();
            }
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on what's the event that will notice you that you have to stop your `AsyncTask`, but generally the most popular approach is having a `Boolean` within your `AsyncTask` extension set to a value (`true` or `false`), and a process within your `doInBackground()` method that will check that variable and call `return` on that method.

So, something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDiscovery extends AsyncTask<Void, HostBean, Void> {
  Boolean running = true;

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while (running) {
      // Do your stuff
      ...

      if (whatEverYouNeedToHappen() == true)
        running = false;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

There's not a "more direct" way of terminating that job without crashing with good practices.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel your asynctask just check isCancelled() once in a while:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Even though some request was made, your async task will wait until it finishes and make the checking again

To set cancelled you just need to get your asynctask instance and use the method .cancel(boolean)